# ValueError: Expected object or value - reading open Recipes data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read a Json file. The code is successfully picking the file but not reading the data successfully and recipes = pd.read_json(data_json) is showing the error ValueError: Expected object or value. I am using the following Code

```
with open('recipeitems-latest.json', 'r',encoding ="utf8") as f:
     data = (line.strip() for line in f)
     data_json = format(','.join(data))
recipes = pd.read_json(data_json)
```

Here is the json data which I am trying to read:

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5160756b96cc62079cc2db15"
    },
    "name": "Drop Biscuits and Sausage Gravy",
    "ingredients": "Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespoons Baking Powder\n1/2 teaspoon Salt\n1-1/2 stick (3/4 Cup) Cold Butter, Cut Into Pieces\n1-1/4 cup Butermilk\n SAUSAGE GRAVY\n1 pound Breakfast Sausage, Hot Or Mild\n1/3 cup All-purpose Flour\n4 cups Whole Milk\n1/2 teaspoon Seasoned Salt\n2 teaspoons Black Pepper, More To Taste",
    "url": "assasasasa",
    "image": "saassasasa",
    "ts": {
        "$date": 1365276011104
    },
    "cookTime": "PT30M",
    "source": "thepioneerwoman",
    "recipeYield": "12",
    "datePublished": "2013-03-11",
    "prepTime": "PT10M",
    "description": "Late Saturday afternoon, after Marlboro Man had returned home with the soccer-playing girls, and I had returned home with the..."
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5160756d96cc62079cc2db16"
    },
    "name": "Hot Roast Beef Sandwiches",
    "ingredients": "12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)\n1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)\n1 pound Cheese (Provolone, Swiss, Mozzarella, Even Cheez Whiz!)\n1/4 cup Mayonnaise\n3 Tablespoons Grated Onion (or 1 Tbsp Dried Onion Flakes))\n1 Tablespoon Poppy Seeds\n1 Tablespoon Spicy Mustard\n1 Tablespoon Horseradish Mayo Or Straight Prepared Horseradish\n Dash Of Worcestershire\n Optional Dressing Ingredients: Sriracha, Hot Sauce, Dried Onion Flakes Instead Of Fresh, Garlic Powder, Pepper, Etc.)",
    "url": "sasasasasa",
    "image": "sasasasasa",
    "ts": {
        "$date": 1365276013902
    },
    "cookTime": "PT20M",
    "source": "thepioneerwoman",
    "recipeYield": "12",
    "datePublished": "2013-03-13",
    "prepTime": "PT20M",
    "description": "When I was growing up, I participated in my Episcopal church's youth group, and I have lots of memories of weekly meetings wh..."
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5160756f96cc6207a37ff777"
    },
    "name": "Morrocan Carrot and Chickpea Salad",
    "ingredients": "Dressing:\n1 tablespoon cumin seeds\n1/3 cup / 80 ml extra virgin olive oil\n2 tablespoons fresh lemon juice\n1 tablespoon honey\n1/2 teaspoon fine sea salt, plus more to taste\n1/8 teaspoon cayenne pepper\n10 ounces carrots, shredded on a box grater or sliced whisper thin on a mandolin\n2 cups cooked chickpeas (or one 15- ounce can, drained and rinsed)\n2/3 cup / 100 g  dried pluots, plums, or dates cut into chickpea-sized pieces\n1/3 cup / 30 g fresh mint, torn\nFor serving: lots of toasted almond slices, dried or fresh rose petals - all optional (but great additions!)",
    "url": "sasasasasa",
    "image": "sasasasasa",
    "ts": {
        "$date": 1365276015332
    },
    "datePublished": "2013-01-07",
    "source": "101cookbooks",
    "prepTime": "PT15M",
    "description": "A beauty of a carrot salad - tricked out with chickpeas, chunks of dried pluots, sliced almonds, and a toasted cumin dressing. Thank you Diane Morgan."
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5160757096cc62079cc2db17"
    },
    "name": "Mixed Berry Shortcake",
    "ingredients": "Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespoons Baking Powder\n3 Tablespoons Sugar\n1/2 teaspoon Salt\n1-1/2 stick (3/4 Cup) Cold Butter, Cut Into Pieces\n1-1/4 cup Buttermilk\n1/2 teaspoon Almond Extract (optional)\n Berries\n2 pints Mixed Berries And/or Sliced Strawberries\n1/3 cup Sugar\n Zest And Juice Of 1 Small Orange\n SWEET YOGURT CREAM\n1 package (7 Ounces) Plain Greek Yogurt\n1 cup Cold Heavy Cream\n1/2 cup Sugar\n2 Tablespoons Brown Sugar",
    "url": "assasasasaas",
    "image": "asasasasasa",
    "ts": {
        "$date": 1365276016700
    },
    "cookTime": "PT15M",
    "source": "thepioneerwoman",
    "recipeYield": "8",
    "datePublished": "2013-03-18",
    "prepTime": "PT15M",
    "description": "It's Monday! It's a brand new week! The birds are chirping! The coffee's brewing! Everything has such hope and promise!     A..."
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5160757496cc6207a37ff778"
    },
    "name": "Pomegranate Yogurt Bowl",
    "ingredients": "For each bowl: \na big dollop of Greek yogurt\n2 tablespoons fresh pomegranate juice\na drizzle of honey\na handful of puffed quinoa crisps (or other cereal/granola)\nsprinkling of toasted sunflower seeds\noptional: whole pomegranate seeds or fresh/dried rose petals, a bit of bee pollen",
    "url": "http://www.101cookbooks.com/archives/pomegranate-yogurt-bowl-recipe.html",
    "image": "http://www.101cookbooks.com/mt-static/images/food/breakfast_yogurt_bowl.jpg",
    "ts": {
        "$date": 1365276020318
    },
    "datePublished": "2013-01-20",
    "source": "101cookbooks",
    "recipeYield": "Serves 1.",
    "prepTime": "PT5M",
    "description": "A simple breakfast bowl made with Greek yogurt, fresh pomegranate juice, puffed quinoa cereal, toasted sunflower seeds, and honey."
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5160757596cc62079cc2db18"
    },
    "name": "Krispy Easter Eggs",
    "ingredients": "4 Tablespoons Butter\n1 package (10 Ounces) Mini Marshmallows\n6 cups Rice Krispies\n Assorted Sprinkles\n Small Chocolate Easter Eggs\n Plastic Easter Eggs",
    "url": "http://thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/2013/03/krispy-easter-eggs/",
    "image": "http://static.thepioneerwoman.com/cooking/files/2013/03/DSC_9637.jpg",
    "ts": {
        "$date": 1365276021992
    },
    "cookTime": "PT5M",
    "source": "thepioneerwoman",
    "recipeYield": "12",
    "datePublished": "2013-03-25",
    "prepTime": "PT20M",
    "description": "Imagine the Easter Bunny laying an egg.     Wait. That’s not anatomically possible.     And anyway, the Easter Bunny is a b..."
}]
```

Here is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 608, in read_json
    result = json_reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 731, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 753, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 857, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 1089, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Any help would be appreciated. As I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
recipes = pd.read_json('recipeitems-latest.json')
```

should work

Comment: Not working  unfortunately - Still giving the error: ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: @AtaUrRahmanMalik forget about the other lines of code.. you don't need to `open` the json fille.. pandas takes care of it all.. so use just this one line.

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. tried to execute just one line and got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: I have even validated the json format on https://jsonlint.com/ ... its valid. still giving the same error

Comment: @AtaUrRahmanMalik i am not having an error on my machine. 
Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using Pandas 1.0.4 ... Which seems to be the latest verison. Still giving the sam error ..

Comment: if you are using jupyter notebook, trying restarting the kernel.

Comment: I am using pyCharm and have already restarted the IDE. :(. Will there be different code for PyCharm?

Comment: No. you shoudn't have different code for pycharm neither. Now please can you show  the exact error `traceback` ? Thanks!

Comment: You can also try to check the `path` of your json file if it is correct

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to this platform... when i am trying to copy and paste the traceback, its giving me the error that my message is too long. So here is it in segments:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 608, in read_json
    result = json_reader.read()

Comment: File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 731, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 753, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "C:\Users\Ata.Malik\PycharmProjects\First_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 857, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()

Comment: The file path is correct, as my original code is successfully reading the file. The file is in project folder... i.e. ...\First_Project ....

Comment: For more readability of your `error` you can `edit` your question and add it there (in one chunk and all)

Comment: Just added the traceback at the end of my question.Thanks

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `json_normalize` here:

```
with open('recipeitems-latest.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                 name                                        ingredients  ...                  _id.$oid       ts.$date
0     Drop Biscuits and Sausage Gravy  Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespo...  ...  5160756b96cc62079cc2db15  1365276011104
1           Hot Roast Beef Sandwiches  12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (...  ...  5160756d96cc62079cc2db16  1365276013902
2  Morrocan Carrot and Chickpea Salad  Dressing:\n1 tablespoon cumin seeds\n1/3 cup /...  ...  5160756f96cc6207a37ff777  1365276015332
3               Mixed Berry Shortcake  Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespo...  ...  5160757096cc62079cc2db17  1365276016700
4             Pomegranate Yogurt Bowl  For each bowl: \na big dollop of Greek yogurt\...  ...  5160757496cc6207a37ff778  1365276020318
5                  Krispy Easter Eggs  4 Tablespoons Butter\n1 package (10 Ounces) Mi...  ...  5160757596cc62079cc2db18  1365276021992
```

Comment: Thanks @NYC Coder .. Its giving me another error Unfortunately .. json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: When I read the file using the open and .read() method and printed it .. its printing the following string:
ï»¿[{
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "5160756b96cc62079cc2db15"
 },
 "name": "Drop Biscuits and Sausage Gravy",
 "ingredients": "Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespoons Baking .....PLUS THE REST OF THE FILE ...

DO you think the error in the load might be due to ï»¿ at the start of the string?

Comment: Yes the JSON has to start with [ or {. No other character should be before that.

Comment: I have skipped the first few characters to start the Json with [ ... Now its giving me error on the second record .. The error is:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 18 column 2 (char 925)

Line 18 contains }, Than line 19 contains the next record. Any ideas?

Comment: There's probably some other character now. Can you validate your JSON? Also does your code work for the JSON you posted above?

Comment: I have validated the json and it seeme to be fine. But the code is still not working :(

Comment: Can you paste your original JSON in your question?

Comment: Original Json has around 90K records and is 130MBs... I have pasted a snippet of that (which I am trying to read) ... I can paste it again, but its going to be same as above? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: The snippet you posted above works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I am trying to run it in pyCharm. I have restarted the IDE a few times. Still not working. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had the same issue.
Try removing all square brackets in this json file.
I think json parser treats them as an array and fails to convert to Dataframe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).